# jqPlot Using manually defined tick labels with canvastickrenderer

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I need to define the tick labels on the x-axis manually.
It works fine as long as I use the `CategoryAxisRenderer`, but I want to rotate the labels using `tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer`.
Now, the x-axis is labeled automatically from 0 to xx in single steps.

What do I have to do, that the manually defined array is used?

The complete code with rotated labels looks like:

```
`$(document).ready(function () {
    var data_array = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
    var s1 = new Array;
    var s2 =  new Array;
    var ticks = new Array();

      $.each(data_array, function (j, elem) {
            $.each(elem, function (i, elem) {
            s1[i] = parseInt(elem['up']);
            s2[i] = parseInt(elem['down']);
            ticks[i] = parseInt(elem['minute']);
            if(ticks[i]%5!=0){
                ticks[i]='';
            }
            });
   $.jqplot(elem['name'], [s1,s2],{
       title:elem['name'],
        stackSeries: true, 
    seriesColors:['#33CC00','#FF3300'],         
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
             rendererOptions: {
                 fillToZero: true,
                varyBarColor: true
              }
        },
        axes: {
            yaxis: {  pad: 1.05},
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks,
                showLabel: true,
                tickOptions: {
                     angle: 30,
                     labelPosition:'start',
                 },
            }
        },
        axesDefaults: {
              tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        }
       }//end jqplot
   );
    });
 });`
```

At the moment the ticks array is just filled with numbers, but it will hold some text labels later.
When I comment out `tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer`, my ticks array is shown as x-axis labels.

I tried several options, but couldn't find a solution.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this problem. 
I am not sure why, but providing space characters like `ticks[i]=' '` instead of `ticks[i]=''` solved it.